# Can't join a domain from 1 PC (others work)

Tags: domain, active-directory

I have a PC which is essential to the business as it runs our ironically named label system 'NiceLabel'. However since a colleague was too impatient to restart the machine when joining the PC to the domain it has decided that it doesn't want to join the domain... ever again!

I've renamed the PC and made it a member of a workgroup, when I try to join it to the domain it returns an error "The specified server cannot perform the requested operation" but it works for other PCs except this one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything informative in the system error log?

There's also a file NETSETUP.log, and another specifically for active directory that I can't remember the name of, that may contain informative errors.

Comment: Please check the event log of the client and the DC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I ensured the PC was a member of a workgroup with a NEW hostname and rebooted.

Then on the DC I deleted the Computer Object from AD, the DNS record and DHCP lease.

I then joined the domain and rebooted and ensured the Computer Object was enabled and created the DNS record manually and it seemed to fix the problem.

Haven't noticed any issues since then and the PC in question is the most heavily used machine on our network.

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if that PC is already registered in AD. If the computer exists there, and the PC itself doesn't think it's on the domain you can't re-add it.

Just delete it from AD and then re-add it from the PC itself.

Comment: Using 'Active Directory Users and Computers' in Admin tools, in Control Panel. Or just open it in mmc directly. Sorry, should have mentioned that to start with.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look round google throws up a bit on this

[Link](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=The+specified+server+cannot+perform+the+requested+operation&btnG=)

Have you recently serviced pack the machine?

Is the date and time matching to server? (this can cause strange things)

Is there still a record of the machine on the server (AD?)

Sure there are many more options but maybe take a look at some of those google results to see if you can eliminate a few

hope that helps a little

Comment: PC hasn't been serviced pack for a while (has Service Pack 2)

Date and Time match.

There is a record in AD but appears disabled, even when I enable it, it still doesn't work.

I did notice it didn't have a DNS record which I created but that didn't help either!

Comment: Personally I would remove the record for the PC in AD so that you are adding the PC as a new computer...Does anything show in the PC event log as mentioned by pauska?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the fully qualified domain name. If the domain is named "ACMEDOMAIN" and the suffix is "local", try to join the domain with "ACMEDOMIAN.local".

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily set your primary DNS server to the ip address of the domain controller.  This will assure its connecting properly.  After you have joined the domain, you can change the dns.  Although I would recommend leaving it as the dc ip.

Comment: This does not address the issue.  The server is not performing the request and as noted by others, the issue is related to a computer account and an improper remove/add to domain

Answer (score 0):

The above link is more informative to your problem.
Additionally 
I suggest you to Check the Domain whether it is able to accept dynamic changes to hostnames.
check the time zone levels,
This error mostly due to Netlogon problems,Just Restart the netlogon service

Hope it helps you..

Thanks
Crew.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, issue resolved after Assigning Static IP to client PC

Try to set **Static IP** address and check

Hope this will solve your problem